# Boost cannot find headers for UUID on CentOS

Tags: c++, boost, centos, g++, openvz

I'm trying to compile code with `g++` (`-I/usr/include` flag is present and `yum install boost-devel qt-devel` has been executed)

but have an error

> boost/uuid/uuid_generators.hpp: No such file or directory

Is it because of an old boost version or is it related to invocation? `ls /usr/include/boost/` does not show presence of this folder too.

`Linux version 2.6.32-042stab140.4 (kbuild-rh6-x64) (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-18) (GCC) )`

```
g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-23)
```

boost version `boost-1.41.0`

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/) `boost.uuid` wasn't available until version 1.42.0.  Your versions of both `boost` and `g++` are *very* old.  An update would almost certainly be worth the effort.

Comment: ok, so what is the best way to install newer version of boost on such an old centos and is there a simple way omitting compiling from source code?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the solution was to install boost version higher than `1.42.0` to have that header available as suggested in comments.

Installing it (`1.55.0`) [from different repository](https://centos.pkgs.org/6/okey-x86_64/boost-devel-1.55.0-25.el6.x86_64.rpm.html) solved the issue

```
$ yum install http://repo.okay.com.mx/centos/6/x86_64/release/okay-release-1-1.noarch.rpm
$ yum install boost-devel
```